# An $.ajax() call inside of element .each() function causing 'too much recursion' error

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code is intended to look for an element, `.placeholder` in this case, get an attribute (`data_id`) from that element and then use that value to asynchronously request a snippet of html, which, if successful, will be appended to the element.

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  var params = {};
  $( ".placeholder" ).each(function(i){
      params['id'] = $(this).attr('data_id');
      $.ajax({
          url: 'http://example.com/endpoint',
          type: 'POST',
          data: params
      })
      .done(function(html){
          $(this).html( html ); 
      });
  });
});
</script>
<body>
<div class="placeholder" data_id="1234"></div>
</body>
```

When I run this it fails, Firefox with 'too much recursion' and points to the jQuery source. Is there an issue in my code or at least a way to debug what is causing the issue?

Comment: If there are 500 ".placeholder", you launch 500 ajax requests at a time... Maybe not a good idea.

Comment: @jeremy there is only 1

Comment: @Vohuman i've edited so that it is clear what params is

Comment: @charlietfl - `params` is a key/value pair of `{"id": "1234"}`

Comment: How do you debug it? Try remove this line `element.html( html );`. Does it remove error? If ya, you know from where comes from your issue. Anyway, you have to provide minimalistic sample code to replicate your issue. FYI, using `.empty()` is useless in this case

Comment: After a quick look, I would guess it is because every time you call ".done" you are adding HTML inside the DIV.placeholder from INSIDE the loop. Therefore, the each fires again, adds HTML again, etc.

Comment: @mrunion - that was my assumption too; however, I've checked the network tab and the ajax request doesn't even start (or get listed). So it appears to be breaking before that could happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong reference on the `.placeholder` element inside of the `done` callback.

Try:

```
  var params = {};
  $( ".placeholder" ).each(function(i){
      var that = $(this);
      params['id'] = that.attr('data_id');
      $.ajax({
          url: 'http://example.com/endpoint',
          type: 'POST',
          data: params
      })
      .done(function(html){
          that.html( html ); 
      });
  });
```

`this` inside of the `done` callback refers to the jqXHR object which doesn't have an `html` function. `$(jqXHR)` adds the `html` function, but it is not functional since the underlying object is not a DOM element.